# Does the Yagmur Continental hotel in Dubai really exist?

Tags: hotels, dubai

I've received this link about the hotel:
http://yagmurcontinental.besaba.com/Home/
but I have two questions:

1. Why is its address "PO Box"? What about its real address?
2. Why is it not in sites such as www.booking.com?

Is this a fake hotel?

Comment: PO Boxes in Dubai for hotels seems quite common. Look [at the page for the Sheraton Deira hotel in Dubai](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/preferredguest/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=724), which I can personally confirm exists, and you'll see they give their address as a PO Box too

Comment: @Karlson: But how do you actually get to the hotel if you only know a P.O. box number? The one you link to at least discloses which street it is on, whereas the physical location of the hotel the OP has found seems to be a complete secret.

Comment: [Hmmmm.](http://yagmurcontinental.esy.es)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not the OP.  I just reformatted the question.

Comment: If you dig down into the "Contacts" section of the linked web page, there's actually a location pinpointed on a Google map there.  [Here's the Street View from that spot, taken October 2014.](https://goo.gl/maps/LJ9L4)  Either that spot is a fake location, or the hotel is less than a year old.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert In Dubai, it's quite possible for a hotel to appear from thin air/dessert in under a year! Doesn't mean it has done, mind...

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Who knew Istanbul and Dubai had so similar climates? And _both_ hotels have a bar which is "a traditional meeting spot for prominent artists, business leaders and Prague´s cultural elite"...

Comment: There's [one in Senegal too](http://www.comfortablehotelresorts.hol.es/).

Comment: @Karlson: Sorry, I confused you with Gagravarr.

Comment: Dear OP:  Why do you believe the hotel might exist?  Where did you hear about it?  Who sent you the link?  Please [edit] your question and clarify, then ping me once you have done so.

Answer (score 10):

Well, IF we're very generous, it might be a real hotel but I can't find a sign of it online, so it's either very, very new, or just changed names.

However, the site you've been sent? Fake. Or at least, very dishonest.  [The photo of one of the rooms they've used](http://yagmurcontinental.besaba.com/gallery/708c8657a6b01e711dfba01c75f4a16a_430x282.jpg) is actually from the Hotel Susesi Luxury Resort in Turkey.

[Example posting for this hotel](http://www.e-ck.cz/dovolena/turecko/turecka-riviera/hotel-susesi-luxury-resort-106143) - check the 5th image, identical.

Comment: And the lobby http://yagmurcontinental.besaba.com/Contacts/ is actually from this hotel in Hamburg: http://media.stgeorg.superbude.de/media/images.php?category=/mediaserver/mediafiles/images/Fotograf:+Christian+Perl (last image)

Comment: As a cherry on top, *.besaba.com is a free hosting site.  How many 5-star hotels can't afford to pay for hosting or their own domain?

Comment: To expand on your fake photos, their [main photo of the hotel](http://yagmurcontinental.besaba.com/gallery/b2413162678be0198ae17ea291dab3e6_1200x535.jpg) is actually a picture of the [A-ONE The Royal Cruise Hotel](http://www.a-onehotel.com/pattaya/) in Pattaya, Thailand.